# Error when try run Weld Se Applicaton - Weld SE container cannot be initialized - no bean archives found

Tags: java, gradle, jboss-weld, weld-se

I create a simple JavaSE app using Weld SE. 
I'm I try to run with gradle run it throws an exception:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:runmai 17, 2016 12:55:55 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.3.4 (Final)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-002009: Weld SE container cannot be initialized - no bean archives found
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.createDeployment(Weld.java:690)

        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:570)
        at br.com.alexpfx.crawler.run.Main.main(Main.java:14)
 FAILED
1 result found for 'bean-discovery-mode'Finding with Options: Case Insensitive

y
bean-discovery-mode
1 found
Find






Replace in current buffer
Replace
Replace All
Gradle: runFile 0Project 0No Issuessrc\main\resources\META-INF\beans.xml10:1
CRLFUTF-8XML1 update
```

What I understand is that it cannot find beans.xml file. But it is there in src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
bean-discovery-mode="all"
        version="1.1">


</beans>
```

My main class is:

```
package br.com.alexpfx.crawler.run;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.*;
import javax.enterprise.inject.*;
import javax.inject.*;
import br.com.alexpfx.crawler.*;
public class Main {

    @Inject
    private @Named("SuperMarket") Crawler crawler;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        Main main = container.instance().select(Main.class).get();
        main.run();
        weld.shutdown();
    }


    public void run() {

        System.out.println (crawler);

    }
}
```

the build gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'



repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies{
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.9.1'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.se/weld-se-core
    compile group: 'org.jboss.weld.se', name: 'weld-se-core', version: '2.3.4.Final'



}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
version = '1.0'
mainClassName = 'br.com.alexpfx.crawler.run.Main'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `gradle run` does not build the jar file for your app.  It simply compiles the classes and runs the main class with the resources directory on the classpath (do `gradle --info run` to see this for yourself).  Weld requires a [bean archive](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/ee.html#packaging-and-deployment) which is a jar file that contains `META-INF/beans.xml` or a war file that contains `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml`.  It's not enough for `beans.xml` to just be on the classpath.

To get around this, since you're using the application plugin, just do a `gradle installDist` and run the shell script or batch file in `build/install/myapp/bin`.

Comment: task installDist not found

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the solution provided by @drenedo (sorry I don't have enough reputation for comment), the following code works fine with me:

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
    exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
}
classes {
    doLast{
        copy {
            from('src/main/resources') { include 'META-INF/beans.xml' }
            into "$buildDir/classes/java/main/"
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm a little confused about what the following code is intended for. Since `src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml` and `$buildDir/classes/main/META-INF/beans.xml` are not directories, this code would cause an error. So I just simply delete it:

```
inputs.dir 'src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml'
outputs.dir "$buildDir/classes/main/META-INF/beans.xml"
```

And the solution answered by @J. Lenthe also works fine with me.

Also you can try this [bean-discovery-problems-when-using-weld-se-with-gradle-application-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325614/7701089) :

```
task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/main/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/java/main"
}
processResources.dependsOn copyResources
```

**Gradle 4+ uses a different output directory for the classes, so remember to use `${buildDir}/classes/java/main` instead of `${buildDir}/classes/main`.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding sourceSets.main.resources in the build.gradle:

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
   exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
}
  classes {
   inputs.dir 'src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml'
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/classes/main/META-INF/beans.xml"
} << {
   copy {
      from('src/main/resources') { include 'META-INF/beans.xml' }
      into "$buildDir/classes/main/"
   }
}
```

With the given example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'



repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies{
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.9.1'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.se/weld-se-core
    compile group: 'org.jboss.weld.se', name: 'weld-se-core', version: '2.3.4.Final'
}

sourceSets.main.resources {
   exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
}
  classes {
   inputs.dir 'src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml'
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/classes/main/META-INF/beans.xml"
} << {
   copy {
      from('src/main/resources') { include 'META-INF/beans.xml' }
      into "$buildDir/classes/main/"
   }
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
version = '1.0'
mainClassName = 'br.com.alexpfx.crawler.run.Main'
```